# what is the easy way of showing xml data in aspx in some sort of data container?

Tags: asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

what is the easy way of showing xml data in aspx in some sort of data container? 
in fx a gridview - note that the xml is in a tree structure

```
<element1>
   <element2>
      <element3>
         <element4>
           ......
</element1>
```

and i also have a schema that defines the xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Data.DataSet has a method named ReadXml() which will turn that XML (w/ or w/o schema) into a DataSet, which you can bind to your GridView as its data source.